# How to enable disable updates to Microsoft Edge Legacy AND Microsoft Edge Chromium

Tags: chromium, microsoft-edge, auto-updates, legacy

Looking for a solution that works for both Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML) [sometimes called Legacy Edge] AND Microsoft Edge (Chromium).  I would like to block updates then unblock updates when I'm ready to check over things when the update is done.  Ideally the solution would also work when a manual update is accidentally initiated by going to "About Microsoft Edge" [for people that are using Edge (Chromium)].

One person's solution for stopping (EdgeHTML) from doing silent automatic updating is via this registry solution:

Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate

REG_DWORD in that key named: AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes

Set AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes to 0

BUT, that solution was provided as a means to stop Edge (EdgeHTML) from being updated.

**QUESTIONS**: Does anyone know if that solution really works? Any caveats?  Does Edge (Chromium) check the above key value too?

**QUESTION**: does this temporary solution seem solid?:

1) Disabled Windows 10 silent automatic updates: Solution:
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
REG_DWORD: NoAutoUpdate = 1

Therefore, if the Windows OS isn't getting updates, Edge (EdgeHTML) won't be getting updated.

2) For Edge (Chromium) I've blocked this in the firewall: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\EdgeUpate\MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe
and that absolutely stops accidental updates occurring when a person checks "About Microsoft Edge".  I assume that will also stop silent auto-updating as on the assumption that it would also need to use MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe but I'm not yet sure.  Will test the next time an update is available.

3) I have done the following registry edit but am not sure if it's needed.  I think it does serve a purpose because if Edge checks the value and decides not to check for updates, that's better than the precess trying to check for updates but erroring out because it can't, due to not being able to get through the firewall):
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate
REG_DWORD: AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes = 0

Thanks in advance for any advice/confirmations you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

> That solution was provided as a means to stop the legacy flavor of Edge from being updated to the chromium based Edge.

The registry key you indicated prevents Chromium Edge from being updated.  It does not prevent Chromium Edge from being installed.

You can't actually block Edge (EdgeHTML) updates, if you install cumulative updates.  **Only the appropriate version of EdgeHTML can run on whatever version of Windows 10 you are running.**

> Does anyone know if that solution would work for what I'm looking for (AND would it work ONLY for the legacy flavor or Chromium as well)?

If you are blocking cumlative updates from being installed you are already blocking Edge (EdgeHTML) updates from being installed.  Similar to that of Internet Explorer on Windows the build is directly linked to the version of Windows you are using.  **So the solution would prevent Edge (Chromium) updates from being installed.**  It is important to point out, that Edge (Chromium) has not fully replaced Edge (EdgeHTML) at this time, and Microsoft has not provide any timeline when that might happen.

> If someone knows of a better solution, what is it and will the solution work for both the legacy and Chromium flavors of Edge?

There isn't a single solution.  Edge (EdgeHTML) updates are handled through Windows Updates, specifically cumulative for the appropriate version of Windows 10.  Likewise, Edge (Chromium) updates are handle entirely separate.  **It should be made clear that the policy documentation for Microsoft Edge, [Microsoft Edge - Update policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-update-policies), only applies to Edge (Chromium) 77+ and absolutely does not apply to any version of Edge (EdgeHTML).**